# Is there a way to build and run .xcodeproj file from zipped project?

Tags: xcode, ios11

I have an old project that already published on the Appstore a while ago, which is not compatible with the recent iOS 11. Now I want to submit an update to make my App available on the Appstore again, but for some reason I can not find the Xcode project on my computer. The only thing I found on my computer is the zipped project, which I can browse its contents, but there is no "xcodeproj" file within it, and the nib files are not openable as I'm getting "Interface Builder cannot open compiled nibs." error every time I double click on them. Is there a way to rebuild and run my project? instead of starting my project from scratch. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Update: I have this black icon with "exec" within the zipped file, which has no extension, but when I open it with Xcode I get a window with this black image in it, is it the .xcodeproj file?

[image]
[image]

Comment: `but there is no "xcodeproj"` You would need the complete project folder, just a `.xcodeproj` wont help you. Perhaps you can back trace and check your emails or shared drives. But if you dont have source code, you wont be able to do anything I guess.

Comment: @GoodSp33d Thanks for taking time to answer my question, please see my update. Thanks

Comment: Thats your compiled code. Once you are able to successfully build and run your project, Xcode would be generating `.app` for simulators which contains all the compiled code in binary formats. Am not really sure if you can reverse engineer `.app` to source code, but if you are not able to locate corresponding source code, not really sure.

Comment: @GoodSp33d I appreciate your help anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nib file is just a UI design file. You can use it to design a layout and work with cocoa class. You can't use this project simply with Nib file.